Boost asio serial port premature completion on async_read
I have a class that wraps a boost::asio::serial_port on a Windows system. I use it to start asynchronous reads on a supplied buffer.
It works well in most cases when there is data in the queue before I start the async_read call (I tried to poll this with the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-clearcommerror function).
However, when no data is present, my async call completes with bytes_read = 0 and error_code = success.
I tried to debug the issue, and when I do the exact same call, but wait for the bytes to arrive for reading I read all the expected bytes.
Is there any way this can happen that is documented properly, or might this be a bug?
Here is the offending function:
bool stream_channel_serial_device::async_read_bytes(
    std::span<uint8_t>   buffer,
    completion_handler&& handler
)
{
    // this is called with a buffer size of 536 bytes
    boost::asio::async_read(
        serial_port_,
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer), // the size of the buffer is 536 bytes
        [this,
         handler = std::move(handler)]
        (boost::system::error_code const& ec, std::size_t bytes_read) {
            if (ec) {
                // THIS IS NOT TRIGGERED (i.e., ec is success),
                // BUT bytes_read is 0!
                log_error("Error reading data package: " + ec.message());
            }

            handler(rx_status{ec, bytes_read});
        }
    );

    return true;
}

Note that:
The serial port is a member variable:
boost::asio::serial_port serial_port_;
Also, the serial port is a virtual com port, but this has not caused any other issues (and really should fully emulate a COM port).
EDIT:
Added the output from using https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html
It clearly shows a premature entering of the handler after reading 0 bytes and with no error code (handler 432).
@asio|1732123199.067050|<428|
@asio|1732123199.067050|>429|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=536
@asio|1732123199.071049|429^430|in 'async_read' (.\build\default\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\bo:373)
@asio|1732123199.071049|429*430|handle@00000204B3E829C0.async_read_some
@asio|1732123199.098571|<429|
@asio|1732123199.098571|>430|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=536
@asio|1732123199.101569|430^431|in 'async_read' (.\build\default\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\bo:373)
@asio|1732123199.101569|430*431|handle@00000204B3E829C0.async_read_some
@asio|1732123199.130571|<430|
@asio|1732123199.130571|>431|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=536
@asio|1732123199.131573|431|handle@00000204B3E829C0.close
@asio|1732123199.139613|431^432|in 'async_read' (.\build\default\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\bo:373)
@asio|1732123199.139613|431*432|handle@00000204B3E829C0.async_read_some
@asio|1732123199.140618|<431|
@asio|1732123199.161532|>432|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=0

Edit 2
It seems only to happen if data has been written to the serial port first. If I do not write first, it will wait for data.
Edit 3
If I set a timeout on the serial port via the native_handle() on Windows, I do not get the issue (but then I'm relying on my data coming within a specified period and my code is not platform independent anymore).

You are using to simple API. There is a way to define what condition should be met to report a result. Since you are using serial port I suspect you would like to read data line by line, so just use: boost::asio::async_read_until(serial_port_, buffer, '\n', ....

If you have fixed size data to read use async_read_at.

@MarekR, Serial is not an AsyncRandomAccessReadDevice.
Also, this simply skips bytes, but otherwise it has the same functionality as async_read

@MarekR, regarding your first comment - no, this is not a too simple API, but exactly what I need. I know how many bytes I need to read. The bytes are not ASCII / text, but binary data, so I cannot use termination characters.


I know how many bytes I need to read

So tell Asio:
bool async_read_bytes(std::span<uint8_t> buffer, completion_handler&& handler) {
    static constexpr unsigned bytes_to_read = 536; // buffer.size()?

    asio::async_read(                              //
        serial_port_,                              //
        asio::buffer(buffer),                      //
        asio::transfer_exactly(bytes_to_read),     //
        [/*this,*/ handler = std::move(handler)](error_code const& ec, size_t bytes_read) {
            if (ec) {
                // THIS IS NOT TRIGGERED (i.e., ec is success),
                // BUT bytes_read is 0!
                log_error("Error reading data package: " + ec.message());
            }

            handler(rx_status{ec, bytes_read});
        });

There is asio::transfer_at_least as well. As you know (from the comment) there's also asio::read_until which has many more options, not constrained to delimiter sequences. See e.g. MatchCondition overloads, examples:

Boost ASIO System timer spurious timeout using it to track composed reads on a serial port
a midway solution using regex as match condition, then checks a checksum asio_read_some countinue reading to get all data
A fully dynamic framing protocol unget or similar solution for boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream with a completely context-dependent match condition
a slightly simpler condition that uses a JSON stream reader to detect the end of a full JSON object boost::asio::async_read_until with custom match_char to accept only JSON format

There are other problems with the code, some of which are probably copy/paste due to creating the question (missing/excess rx_status).
Bonus: Idiomatic Initiation Functions
I see you adding non-asio call-backs. This may invite errors when operations are composed, because the associated executors (and other Associated Characteristics) are not preserved. See e.g. boost::asio::bind_executor does not execute in strand
Creating idiomatic async initiations is Not That Hard(TM) anymore these days:
template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_read_bytes(std::span<uint8_t> buffer, CompletionToken&& token) {
    return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, ReadSig>(
        [](auto h, auto& s, auto b) mutable {
            async_read( //
                s, b, asio::transfer_exactly(asio::buffer_size(b)),
                [h = std::move(h)](error_code const& ec, size_t bytes_read) mutable {
                    // add behavior?
                    std::move(h)(ec, bytes_read);
                });
        },
        token, serial_port_, asio::buffer(buffer));
}

Or if you don't even need to add behaviour:
template <asio::completion_token_for<ReadSig> CompletionToken = asio::deferred_t>
auto async_read_bytes(std::span<uint8_t> buffer, CompletionToken&& token = {}) {
    return async_read(serial_port_, asio::buffer(buffer), std::forward<decltype(token)>(token));
}

This makes it so you can use any type of completion handler, including (bound) handlers, futures, c++ coros, etc:
Live On Coliru
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;

void log_error(std::string const& msg) { std::cerr << msg << std::endl; }

struct stream_channel_serial_device {
    stream_channel_serial_device(asio::any_io_executor ex, std::string const& port_name) 
        : serial_port_(ex, port_name) {}

    using ReadSig = void(error_code, size_t);

    // idiomatic ASIO initiation function:
    template <typename CompletionToken>
    auto async_read_bytes(std::span<uint8_t> buffer, CompletionToken&& token) {
        return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, ReadSig>(
            [](auto h, auto& s, auto b) mutable {
                async_read( //
                    s, b, asio::transfer_exactly(asio::buffer_size(b)),
                    [h = std::move(h)](error_code const& ec, size_t bytes_read) mutable {
                        // add behavior?
                        std::move(h)(ec, bytes_read);
                    });
            },
            token, serial_port_, asio::buffer(buffer));
    }

    // but even simpler, if no behaviour needs to be added:
    template <asio::completion_token_for<ReadSig> CompletionToken = asio::deferred_t>
    auto async_read_bytes_simple(std::span<uint8_t> buffer, CompletionToken&& token = {}) {
        return async_read(serial_port_, asio::buffer(buffer), std::forward<decltype(token)>(token));
    }

    asio::serial_port serial_port_;
};

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool io_context(1);
    stream_channel_serial_device device(io_context.get_executor(), "/dev/ttyUSB0");

    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(536);
    device.async_read_bytes(buffer, [](error_code ec, size_t n) {
        std::cout << "Handler read " << n << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    });

    // or the simple version
    device.async_read_bytes_simple(buffer, [](error_code ec, size_t n) {
        std::cout << "Handler read " << n << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    });

    // or e.g. using futures (blocks main thread)
    auto [ec, n] = device.async_read_bytes_simple(buffer, asio::as_tuple(asio::use_future)).get();
    std::cout << "Future read " << n << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

    // or e.g. using C++20 coroutines
    co_spawn(
        io_context,
        [&] -> asio::awaitable<void> {
            error_code ec;
            size_t     n = co_await device.async_read_bytes_simple(buffer);
            if (ec) {
                log_error("Error reading data package: " + ec.message());
            } else {
                std::cout << "Read " << n << " bytes\n";
            }
        },
        asio::detached);

    io_context.join();
}


Somewhat reviewed and posted Bonus implementation examples that show idiomatic ASIO initiation functions

Thanks for the comprehensive answer.
I'll try the transfer_exactly, but the overload I am using is actually using the boost::asio::transfer_all() which in my case translates to transfer_exactly the buffer size. See docs here:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html#boost_asio.reference.async_read.overload1.remarks
Or am I missing something?

Second, even if it turns out I need to use the transfer_exactly, it still feels like a hack, since the call I make returns with 0 bytes read, which is different from the documentation. I suspect this is a Windows only thing, but I'm not sure.

Tried with the transfer_exactly to no help. Same issue as expected (see comment above)

All I can hypothesize is that the device is actually using automatic control codes (STX/ETX handled by interface, or perhaps presence of stop bit?) and thus explicitly sending the "empty packet". In that case you'll just have to ignore (or handle according to the documented device semantics).

It could be the STX/ETX, but in that case it's strange that it works with a synchronous read (where it waits to read all 536 bytes)

@SupAl These things can be timing-dependent, something wich is prone to change when you use a different way of scheduling the IO operations. Of course, it's also possible that something else entirely is the matter, but we'd need a lot more information to both reproduce and analyze such things (the exact software/driver stack, the device in question, the configurations of all of the former, the timing of output and possibly input communication, and potentially any external input triggers).
